# Clojure, return arguments from a function that are then used directly in a hash-map

Tags: clojure

I want to return a list of arguments from a function and have them put straight into a hash-map. I'm using a vector to enclose these arguments, working under the assumption that only one value can be returned from a Clojure function. So on the return part of the call I am wanting to strip away the vector.

This is what the function is successfully returning:

```
[:top-edge {3 [[0 0]]}]
```

As you can see if you strip away the vector you get something that should be able to be placed straight into a hash-map (because it has a key and a value):

```
:top-edge {3 [[0 0]]}
```

I have experimented with `apply` and `flatten`, and know that in some circumstances `concat` can be used for stripping away the outermost vector, but still have not found a solution.

For the moment I have left the code so it is not stripping away the vector, and the error message makes perfect sense: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: [:top-edge {3 [[0 0]]}]`

**Edit:**
Question already answered, but just to show the actual code and what does and does not work. This does work:

```
(conj {:rep (->Blob rgb pos)} (new-edge-map pos edge-keyword seg-id))
```

, and this does not:

```
{:rep (->Blob rgb pos) (apply hash-map (new-edge-map pos edge-keyword seg-id))}
```

The error I get is 'Map literal must contain an even number of forms'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conj`:

```
(conj {} [:top-edge {3 [[0 0]]}])
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `hash-map`:

> Returns a new hash map with supplied mappings.  If any keys are
>     equal, they are handled as if by repeated uses of assoc.

So,

```
(apply hash-map [:top-edge {3 [[0 0]]}])
=> {:top-edge {3 [[0 0]]}}
```

Comment: I tried using like so: `{:a-key "a value" (apply hash-map (a-call an-arg))}`, where `(a-call an-arg)` can be replaced by `[:top-edge {3 [[0 0]]}]`, and got 'Map literal must contain an even number of forms'.

Comment: The problem is that you have `{:a-key "a value" a-hash-map-which-is-also-a-key}` and no value for the second key.

Comment: I tried a few other things as well but could not get them to work either. `(conj {:a-key "a value"} [:top-edge {3 [[0 0]]}])` does work however.

Comment: `(apply hash-map (a call an-arg))` should work if `(a-call an-arg)` returns a vector of two elements like the one you describe.